# Player that can fade out a video in real time

Tags: linux, video

I need a video player (GUI player) that can fade out a video in real time while playing. For instance when I play a 2 minutes length video I'd like to be able to fade it out just when only 1 minute is left.

Is there any player that can do something like that?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it was really necessary to [cross-post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/564777/player-that-can-fade-out-a-video-in-real-time) this question :)